# System.Collections.Generic.List<Plate>' does not contain a definition for 'Time' and no extension method 'Time'

Tags: .net, linq

Here's a LINQ statement that I am trying to execute

```
var usersQuery =
from user in Model.Users
select user.Plates;

var platesQuery =
from plate in usersQuery
group plate by plate.Time into grouping
select grouping;
```

I get the following error

```
System.Collections.Generic.List<AllYourPlates.Domain.Entities.Plate>' does not contain a definition for 'Time' and no extension method 'Time' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<AllYourPlates.Domain.Entities.Plate>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?
```

I can't figure out what the problem is.

Comment: What are you trying to *achieve*? I can see why the query is failing, but not what it's trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`usersQuery` is an `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Plate>>` you can either rectify this in your `platesQuery` like this:

```
var platesQuery = from plates in usersQuery
                  from plate in plates
                  group plate by plate.Time into grouping
                  select grouping;
```

Or flatten out the initial results so you have an `IEnumerable<Plate>` instead:

```
var usersQuery = from user in Model.Users
                 from plate in user.Plates
                 select plate;
```